# How to add an autoincrement field for an existing table and populate it with serial numbers for rows?

Tags: sql, oracle

e.g. I have a table:

```
create table test (testdata varchar2(255));
```

then I need an autoincrement field:

```
alter table test add id numeric(10);

create sequence test_seq 
start with 1 
increment by 1 
nomaxvalue; 

create trigger test_trigger
before insert on test
for each row
begin
select test_seq.nextval into :new.id from dual;
end;
```

what should I do next to populate already existing fields with their serial numbers in "id" ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
update test
set id = test_seq.nextval
```

Comment: So is it always `TABLE_NAME_seq.nextval`?